# Manipulating first child inside DIV as an UL element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have the below HTML elements.

```
<div class="ow_box_empty ow_stdmargin clearfix">
    <div id="avatar-console" class="ow_avatar_console ow_center">
        <div style="height: 190px; background: url(7.jpg) no-repeat;>
            <div style="display: none;" id="avatar-change">
                <a href="http://avatar">Change Avatar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="user_online_wrap">
            <div class="ow_miniic_live"><span class="ow_live_on"></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to wrap the first DIV(inside DIV with id "avatar-console") with an LI tag and insert new LI tag at the end as shown below.

Below is the required ouput.

```
<div class="ow_box_empty ow_stdmargin clearfix">
    <div id="avatar-console" class="ow_avatar_console ow_center">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div style="height: 190px; background: url(7.jpg) no-repeat">
                    <div style="display: none;" id="avatar-change">
                        <a href="http://avatar">Change Avatar</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="star">★</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="user_online_wrap">
            <div class="ow_miniic_live"><span class="ow_live_on"></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried the below code to start with but it gives unwanted results. I am not sure where and how to start on this.

```
$("#avatar-console div:first-child").append('<li class="star">★</li>')
```

**[Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/Purus/U3KC8/](http://jsfiddle.net/Purus/U3KC8/)**

Comment: The code in your question doesn't seem to match the code in your fiddle.

Comment: To make it neat, I have trimeed some unnecessary css attributes and link urls here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/da4dz/

```
$("#avatar-console > div:first")
    .wrap('<ul><li></li></ul>')
    .closest('ul').append('<li class="star">star</li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery wrap() method:

```
$("div:first-child", "#avatar-console").wrap("<ul><li></li></ul>");
```